# iphone - apns alert option (no view option) possible?

Tags: iphone, alert, apple-push-notifications

In the official Apple document it says

> alert
>
> string or
>   dictionary
>
> If this property is included, iOS displays a standard alert. You may specify a string as the value of alert or a dictionary as its value. If you specify a string, it becomes the message text of an alert with two buttons: Close and View. If the user taps View, the application is launched.
>   Alternatively, you can specify a dictionary as the value of alert. See Table 3-2 for descriptions of the keys of this dictionary.

But I wonder if there's any option that I can add to the code to make the push only show "close" button.

Ex of what I have now:
`@"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Update OS\"},\"acme1\":\"updateos\",\"acme2\":42}";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a dictionary. Have a look at Table 3-2 on the same page, for the key `action-loc-key`, it says:

> If a string is specified, displays an alert with two buttons, whose behavior is described in Table 3-1. However, iOS uses the string as a key to get a localized string in the current localization to use for the right button’s title instead of “View”. **If the value is null, the system displays an alert with a single OK button that simply dismisses the alert when tapped.** See “Localized Formatted Strings” for more information.

The single OK button is perhaps what you need.